# What are good books to learn about risk associated with a particular purchase or investment?

Tags: risk, books

Are there any good books that teach the beginner how to estimate the risk associated with a particular purchase or investment?

Qualitative and quantitative methods would be a nice starting point.

Comment: You're quick to "accept" an answer on your questions when requesting multiple sources.  Suggest you wait until more answers are in and judge accordingly, or not accept a single best answer when there isn't necessarily one.

Comment: Yes..no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a basic introduction you may want to check out [Hull's Options Futures & other Derivatives](http://www.rotman.utoronto.ca/~hull/ofod/).

To keep up to date with the quant world you check out [Wilmott](http://www.wilmott.com/magazine.cfm) magazine.

Comment: Can you understand Wilmott magazine if you are not a quant?

Comment: It is certainly more mathematical than many other publications. But there are a lot of simple articles dealing with the recent advancements in risk management and quant finance. If you are just interested in getting a feel of the subject, I would suggest finishing Hull and then decide.